# Obtain path of USB Stick with Terminal on macOS with Python3

Tags: python, macos, terminal, usb, directory-listing

I‘d like to write a Python program which first detects a new USB disk with Terminal on macOS, then returns me the full path to the stick.

I‘ve tried to implement it like that:

```
os.chdir(‘/Volumes‘)
#then do some listing
List = os.listdir()
```

But this returns me just

```
My_USB_Stick
Macintosh HD
```

I have no idea how to get the path of the connected drive, which excludes Macintosh HD…

Any Ideas ?
Looking forward to hearing from you ;)

My_USB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to to it would be:

1. Find a way to list the complete path of all files while performing the `ls` command in python
2. Loop through the list and exclude the `Macintosh HD` file.

There is another easier way to implement the same. You could loop over the `List` and add the current path (`/Volumes/`) to the files/folders in the list. Here is an implementation of the same:

```
import os
os.chdir('/Volumes')
# then do some listing
List = os.listdir()
i = 0
while i < len(List):
    if (List[i] == 'Macintosh HD'):
        del List[i:i+1]
        continue
    else:
        List[i] = '/Volumes/' + List[i]
        i += 1
print(List)
```

Comment: Working awesome Thanks  ✊